# achieving Blurry Shaking in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a website and here is the demo for it
http://benseno.com.tr/demo/oto/
and I want to achieve a Blurry Shaky Animation for an element with Jquery in the footer as in this Photos:
[image]

[image]

[image]

here in the First image this orange Slide comes
Then The "X" `Div` Comes in something like the motion in the Picture, and this is what I'm missing or I want to do, I need all you suggestions for achieving something similar to this motion, you can See What I've Done so far in the Demo, scroll down to the footer
and my script is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 700) {
            $('#footer_img').animate({
                'background-position' : '300px'
            }, 500, 'linear', function() {
                $('#footer_x').fadeIn(10);
                $('#footer_x').animate({
                    'width' : '201px',
                    'height' : '217px'
                }, 200, 'linear');

                $('#footer_x').effect('shake', {
                    times : 1,
                    direction : 'down',
                    distance : 3
                }, 50);

            });

        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
            $('#footer_img').animate({
                'background-position' : '900px'
            }, 1000, 'linear');
            $('#footer_x').fadeOut(100);
        }
    });
</script>
```

any suggestions, advises are really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some css can help 
Demo : http://dabblet.com/gist/5212660

```
.style1 
    { 
     animation-name: shake; 
     animation-duration: 0.8s; 
     transform-origin:50% 50%; 
     animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
     animation-timing-function: linear; 

     -moz-animation-name: shake; 
     -moz-animation-duration: 0.8s; 
     -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%; 
     -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
     -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; 

     -webkit-animation-name: shake; 
     -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s; 
     -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%; 
     -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
    }

    @keyframes shake{ 
     0% { transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg);    } 
     10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);  } 
     20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);     } 
     30% { transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg);     } 
     40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);     } 
     50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);    } 
     60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);     } 
     70% { transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);     } 
     80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);   } 
     90% { transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg);     } 
     100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);     } 
    }  

    @-moz-keyframes shake{ 
     0% {   -moz-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg);    } 
     10% {  -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);  } 
     20% {  -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);     } 
     30% {  -moz-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg);     } 
     40% {  -moz-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);     } 
     50% {  -moz-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);    } 
     60% {  -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);     } 
     70% {  -moz-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);     } 
     80% {  -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }  
     90% {  -moz-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg);     } 
     100% { -moz-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);     } 
    }  

    @-webkit-keyframes shake { 
     0% {   -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg);  } 
     10% {  -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); } 
     20% {  -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);   } 
     30% {  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg);   } 
     40% {  -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); } 
     50% {  -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);   } 
     60% {  -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);   } 
     70% {  -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);   } 
     80% {  -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);   } 
     90% {  -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg);   } 
     100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);   } 
    }
```

Demo : http://dabblet.com/gist/5212660

---

Add Blur

use

```
filter: blur(5px);
// Browser Specific
-webkit-filter: blur(35px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
```

---

Like

```
@-webkit-keyframes shake { 
         0% {   -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg);  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);  } 
         10% {  -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); -webkit-filter: blur(9px); } 
         20% {  -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);   -webkit-filter: blur(8px); } 
         30% {  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg);   } 
         40% {  -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); } 
         50% {  -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);   } 
         60% {  -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);   } 
         70% {  -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);   } 
         80% {  -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);   } 
         90% {  -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg);   } 
         100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);   } 
        }
```

as your need change the values

Checkout http://dabblet.com/gist/5212721

edited only for webkit

try it in chrome only

Comment: Thanks, it's very nice result, but doesn't Give blur, or the same exact motion, but it's similar and really Helpful, I will consider that

Comment: wait give u the blurry stuff

Comment: Thanks good luck for your project try to use css instead js for styling stuff

Comment: yea, but Problem here is about compatibility :-(
Gecko browsers don't support webkit stuff

Comment: Caniuse.com can check everything here

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a number of advices (which are in line to some extend with Sahil Popli's answer)

First of all, as Sahil proposes it would be advisable to use css3 transitions for the animation. This is better because browsers which support it will do a much smoother job with it than the slow and stuttering animation you currently have. Alternatively you can use [this](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) library if you need more control over the animation or simply want to support both older and newer browsers with a smoother animation than you currently have.

Finally getting to the blur part, I just saw Sahil added a note about the filter property whilst I was working on this answer, but I would like to expand on that.

The blur effect can indeed be achieved in webkit based browsers (chrome, safari and in a few months opera as well) using the `-webkit-filter:blur(distance);` function, the problem with this is of course that this is limited to only webkit. Gecko (firefox) however does not support the `blur` function, but it does allow you to refer to a svg filter using a `url()` resource. This might sound complicated, but the only thing you need to do is add the following file alongside your css

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur" x="0" y="0">
      <!-- Change stdDeviation for different amounts of blur -->
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

and rather than using the `blur` function you can now use

```css
-webkit-filter:url(filter.svg#blur);
filter:url(filter.svg#blur);
```

which will work in firefox, safari and chrome. The disadvantage of this is that unlike the `blur` function this can *not* be transitioned using css3 or javascript, thus you can only turn the effect on and off (though you could make a number of stages by adding more blur elements to your svg file).

Now, older IE versions (IE9 and below) also had a proprietary `filter` property which also could be used to add a blur effect, so by adding the following

```css
-webkit-filter:url(filter.svg#blur);
filter:url(filter.svg#blur);
zoom:1;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='2', MakeShadow='false', ShadowOpacity='0')
```

you will have a blur effect in all major browsers with the exception of IE10+. Now, it *is* possible to get it working in IE10 as well, but that would require switching from a `HTML element`, to an `SVG element` to which you would apply the blur filter, which in turn would cause IE9- to miss out (or you would have to use feature detection to use different versions). (You can include bitmap images using the `image` tag inside `svg`s, as is done in for example [this demo](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_svg-filter-effects.htm))

Comment: This library... Cannot be described, it's more than Amazing

Comment: Thanks for this very Rich and Covering Answer, I suggest Combining yours and Sahil's for the total befit of both answers